# Unable to select Visual Studio Profile to Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, publishing

To publish my project, I Builded my Asp.Net MVC Web application, But the publish window is as shown in the picture,The tabs are getting freezed. It is unable to choose any local folder for publish.

[image: Publish Window]

Comment: update visual studio that will work https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26373/publish-preview-not-allowing-selective-publish-of.html

Comment: I would think you should update or even re-install visual studio. It's not a code question anyone can really give you practical help with. Clearly something is wrong or missing with your install. We can't see your machine's config, and we can't see the visual studio source code. Unless VS logs any problems on the machine somewhere which would give people a clue, we can't really give you any concrete advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the updated version of visual studio, now the problem solved.